# How should I call a graph that is not a multigraph?

Tags: graph-theory

Vocabulary question :
A multigraph is a graph that can have several identical edges (same vertices, same direction if directed).

Is there an official name for a graph that is not a multigraph ?

- "Graph" seems too generic, as this describes any kind of graph
- "Simple graph" is already an undirected "not multi" graph with no loops

I didn't manage to find better names for a graph which only constraint would be "no identical edges"... "Monograph" ?

Comment: Well as you state, a "simple graph" is not a multigraph... you should probably state what kind of graph you're looking for, because there's plenty graphs "not a multigraph". In fact, as far as I know, "simple graph" *does* capture all graphs that are not a multigraph. There's nothing about direction in either of their definitions.

Comment: @vrugtehagel I'm simply looking for a generic name for a graph that has no other constraint than "no identical edges". It could be either directed or undirected, have loops or not, doesn't matter. All the other "not a multigraph" names I found have more constraints than just this one.

Comment: Then I think "simple graph" is indeed exactly what you're looking for. Unless you want loops. Then you could probably say "simple graph with loops" (as I don't think there's a name for that). Also, simple graphs are undirected, yes, but so are multigraphs. If you want it to be directed, then just say "directed simple graph". The world of graphs is already too full of definitions, let's not add another term to the book ;) of course, if you're writing an article or paper, define it yourself, and that should be perfectly fine.

Comment: @vrugtehagel Hence my question. If the answer is "there's no name for that", then fine, and that would explain why I didn't find any :) As an aside, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph) disagrees with you regarding the "undirectedness" of multigraphs (ok then it's called a multidigraph, which underlines what you said about graph theory definition bloating...).

Comment: The problem with this kind of question if the answer doesn't exist, is, nobody can definitively say it doesn't exist. I personally don't know it, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist - the same goes for everyone else that doesn't know it. In this case, I'd say, "it doesn't exist". As I said, if you really need a name for it, define it yourself. If you were just interested to find out the name, then I'm sorry, I can't help you further.

Comment: Its called a simple graph. In German: schlichter Graph.

Comment: @Wuestenfux So according to you, a directed "loop enabled" graph allowing only unique edges should also be called a "simple graph" as an undirected loopless one is already called ? Looking at german definitions, do you see a difference between "schlichter" and "einfacher" graphs ?